# How can one compile CoffeeScript during the build phase of a Python packages' distutils installation?

Tags: python, django, coffeescript, distutils, pypi

I'm working on a Python Django package whose front-end components employ a bit of CoffeeScript.

Right now, I have a rather brain-dead external script that takes care of the CoffeeScript compilation. It simply runs a `coffee` compile command for every *.coffee file in a src/coffee/ directory and stores the output in src/static/js -- this similar to how `python ./setup.py build_ext --inplace` stores a C extension's build files in the development source tree.

That works for now, but it's pretty cheesy -- it forces a flat directory structure, and modifies the files in src/static (which is the opposite of what "static" implies).

I want to be maximally pythonic about things, so I looked into modifying `distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler` to run `coffee` as a subcommand of the setup.py "build_ext" subcommand -- I was envisioning the ability to do things like this:

```
% python ./setup.py build_coffee
% python ./setup.py build_coffee --inplace
% python ./setup.py build_ext --inplace # implying 'build_coffee --inplace'
```

... but I found distutils' compiler API to be way too focussed on C compilation nuances that have no analog in this case e.g. preprocessing, linking, etc. I also looked at Cython's code (specifically at Cython's `CCompiler` subclass, which preprocesses .pyx files into .c source) but this looked similarly specialized, and not so appropriate for this case.

Does anyone have a good solution for compiling CoffeeScript with a distutils setup.py script? Or, barring that, a good alternative suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor, not sure if that suits your needs

Comment: I am actually using that package in my base project, in which I'm developing this package alongside a web app that uses it. It's a great package, but it's focus is on automatic deployment of the compiled/compressed assets in a web context -- I can't use it as a generic prerequisite. I'm looking for something more along the lines of how Cython works with distutils (e.g. if you have it installed, it will preprocess and compile as needed). My potential users may not have CoffeeScript installed in the same way, and their webapp deploy methods may not jibe well with django-compressor.

Comment: Whats wrong with binding to django's collectstatic command?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. It just doesn't compile CoffeeScript during the build phase of a Python packages' distutils installation (which is what I am looking to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll this into a custom manage.py command.
[See the official Django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/) this way the script will be run everytime the server is run always resulting in a clean build of your js.

Comment: Good call -- now that you mention it, that's a healthier place for this type of thing in a number of ways. Thanks and salud.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a [pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)* that compiles coffescript into javascript.

So everytime you commit a change in the coffescript, the javascript version is updated.

*pre commit hook: the way to do it depends on the VCS you use, and depends on you using a sane VCS.

Comment: Actually I love pre-commit hooks -- I primarily use git; in this regard, it isn't that nuts -- and in fact I am calling my cheesy compilation batch script with a pre-commit hook at this time. That's all well and good for my development needs and maybe for the patient and interested who clone it off of GitHub, but integrating the 'build system' with my VCS of choice won't fly in something like a CheeseShop source tarball (or an egg, godforbid). That's why I'm looking for a distutils-friendly solution in this case.

Comment: Ok, since you're encouraging me, I'll give a quick try to convince you hahaha .... You want the build system not to depend on the VCS, so that a user can hack and build the module without the need of a VCS. Since you're using git, does it really make sense for a user to hack your module without doing a git fork, and thus commit-hook ability ? Wouldn't that be encouraging a bad practice ? Also, the user needs to install a coffescript compiler to build your module with his modifications, which means that he should be competent enough to use git fork and hooks. Just a quick try, choice is yours

Comment: Hahaha -- the thing about practices is: you have to practice them. Cuz, usually, best practices benefit the greater ecosystem _qua_ the programmer. Distutils is a case in point: it's for the end-user's benefit, we all love to hate it; but at the end of the day the anointedly Pythonic way to install something is with `pip install something` -- which as an end-user I much prefer that, when I'm installing someone elses' packages, vs. messing with a fork full of mystery code. Users at this level are probably quite competent, but if I test their competence they'll be disinclined to use my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at **[DukPy](https://github.com/amol-/dukpy)**... It's a simple javascript interpreter for Python and can compile `CoffeeScript`, `TypeScript`, `BabelJS` and `JSX`. Usage is very simple, just import and compile like this:

```py
import dukpy
dukpy.coffee_compile("CoffeeScript goes here!")
```

**Note:** DukPy is the successor to the [Python-CoffeeScript](https://github.com/doloopwhile/Python-CoffeeScript) package witch is no longer maintained.